# How to block a specific email address domain from being able to submit Drupal webform?

Tags: webforms

I've been trying to find an answer to as per title. How can I block a specific email address domain from being able to submit Drupal webform?

**Example:**

Webform has fields:

*Name, Email address, Subject, Query* - all fields are set to required.

What I want is a webform submission to be blocked when a visitor is trying to submit it using a specific email address domain, for example *@example.com.

I need my Drupal webform to be able to act similarly to a registration form equipped with [User restrictions](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) module.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Shawn, [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module solved my problem. Thanks a a lot for that.